# How to find the maximum frequency a RTL code support?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, system-verilog, fpga, register-transfer-level

I have a very basic question, How do we conclude the maximum freqency my synthesizable RTL code support? where do we check it in Vivado , quartus and Yosys tools

Comment: This should be covered in the documentations of the tools.

Comment: The RTL code is a high level behavioral description and has no concept of maximum frequency. We only get that idea once the RTL has been synthesized into netlist and gone through a fitter to generate post fit netlist. Please look at the reports generated by Quartus and you will see the ones containing fmax of the design for your device.

Answer (score 1):

In case of `Yosys` it is better to use another open source tool like `opensta` which has its repository in the following link https://github.com/The-OpenROAD-Project/OpenSTA, an example for a simple script you can run on that tool to get your timing checks is as follows

```
read_liberty <standard_cell_library_name>
read_verilog <name_of_verilog_file(s))
link_design <name_of_top_module>
create_clock -name clk -period 10 {<name_of_clock_inside_your_module>}
report_checks
```

You can also check their documentation to see how you can do more advanced scripts if you want